# ZonedDateTime to UTC with offset applied?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, utc, zoneddatetime

I am using `Java 8`
This is what my `ZonedDateTime` looks like

```
2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00
```

I get this value as

```
z1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
```

where `z1` is a `ZonedDateTime`.

I wanted to convert this value as `2013-07-10T14:52:49`

How can I do that?

Comment: I still don't understand :D. And how is it different than http://stackoverflow.com/q/35688559/1743880? What do you mean by "convert to `2013-07-10T14:52:49`"?

Comment: apply `+12 hours` to `02:52:49` to make it `14:52:59`, is it clear now?

Comment: So you want to go 12 hours in the future for the same zone offset?

Comment: Yes Sir! that is what I want

Comment: But in your wanted output, there's no zone offset anymore. Also, what if the offset is something with half an hour (it exists...)?

Comment: since the time goes `12 hours` in future, the offset is not required. The point is apply the offset `+` or `-` the value indicated in original variable

Comment: If you remove the zone information, this is no longer a zoned date time...

Comment: Which is fine because I want to convert it into `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: I don't get it. Given your input and the offset, shouldn't the output be 12 hours _earlier_?

Answer (score 26):

It looks like you need to convert to the desired time zone (UTC) before sending it to the formatter.

```
z1.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of("UTC") )
  .format( DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME )
```

should give you something like `2018-08-28T17:41:38.213Z`

Comment: This worked for me:
LocalDateTime _2018_3_13 = LocalDateTime.of(2018, Month.MARCH, 13, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.of(_2018_3_13, ZoneOffset.UTC);
String last = z1.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"))
        .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);

Answer (score 24):

Is this what you want? 
This converts your `ZonedDateTime` to a `LocalDateTime` with a given `ZoneId` by converting your `ZonedDateTime` to an `Instant` before.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(z1.toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Or maybe you want the users system-timezone instead of hardcoded UTC:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(z1.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Comment: Huh... It looks fine to me... You could maybe try with a different browser to check if you have the same issue.

Comment: No need to hardcode `UTC`, you can simply use predefined zone offsets: `ZoneOffset.UTC`

Comment: Thanks for the hint @AndriiAbramov, I edited my answer!

Answer (score 5):

@SimMac Thanks for the clarity. I also faced the same issue and able to find the answer based on his suggestion.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String dateTime = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
        String date = "09/17/2017 20:53:31";
        Integer gmtPSTOffset = -8;
        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(gmtPSTOffset);

        // String to LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTime));
        // Set the generated LocalDateTime's TimeZone. In this case I set it to UTC
        ZonedDateTime ldtUTC = ldt.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println("UTC time with Timezone          : "+ldtUTC);

        // Convert above UTC to PST. You can pass ZoneOffset or Zone for 2nd parameter
        LocalDateTime ldtPST = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(ldtUTC.toInstant(), offset);
        System.out.println("PST time without offset         : "+ldtPST);

        // If you want UTC time with timezone
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" );
        ZonedDateTime zdtPST = ldtUTC.toLocalDateTime().atZone(zoneId);
        System.out.println("PST time with Offset and TimeZone   : "+zdtPST);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Output:

```
UTC time with Timezone          : 2017-09-17T20:53:31Z
PST time without offset         : 2017-09-17T12:53:31
PST time with Offset and TimeZone   : 2017-09-17T20:53:31-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

Answer (score 2):

If `z1` is an instance of `ZonedDateTime`, then the expression

```
z1.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime()
```

evaluates to an instance of `LocalDateTime` with the string representation requested by the OP. This is illustrated by the following program:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZonedDateTime time = ZonedDateTime.now();
    ZonedDateTime truncatedTime = time.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    ZonedDateTime truncatedTimeUtc = truncatedTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    LocalDateTime truncatedTimeUtcNoZone = truncatedTimeUtc.toLocalDateTime();

    System.out.println(time);
    System.out.println(truncatedTime);
    System.out.println(truncatedTimeUtc);
    System.out.println(truncatedTimeUtcNoZone);
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
2020-10-26T16:45:21.735836-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
2020-10-26T16:45:21-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
2020-10-26T19:45:21Z
2020-10-26T19:45:21
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to convert this value as `2013-07-10T14:52:49`

2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00 ≠ 2013-07-10T14:52:49 at UTC

2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00 = 2013-06-09T14:52:49 at UTC (which is obtained by subtracting 12:00 hours of the offset from 2013-07-10T02:52:49).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of("+12:00");
        OffsetDateTime odtGiven = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2013, 7, 10, 2, 52, 49), zoneOffset);
        System.out.println(odtGiven);

        OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odtGiven.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtUtc);
        System.out.println(odtUtc.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2013-07-10T02:52:49+12:00
2013-07-09T14:52:49Z
2013-07-09T14:52:49
```

Learn about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.